# Laravel Eloquent: using whereRaw to search for "LIKE %%"

Tags: sql, laravel, function, eloquent, where-clause

I am trying to sort my table using a `LIKE`

Database Connections: (in case anyone is wondering about this)

```
use App\Models\HmsBbrCategory;
use DB;
```

**Function:** (this is inside a class extends controller)

- the variable `$search_category` has content in its text field so the else should trigger in this case

  ```
  public function fetchcategory($search_category){
    if (empty($search_category)) {
        $search_where = DB::raw('category_id >= 1');
    } else {
        $search_where = DB::raw('category_name LIKE "%Gen%"');
    }
    $all_categories = HmsBbrCategory::whereRaw('category_name LIKE '%Gen%'') 
                                      ->orderBy('category_id', 'ASC')
                                      ->get();
    return response()->json([
        'all_categories'=>$all_categories,
    ]);
  ```

  }

the code above gives the error:

[image: 1]

The problem is probably the `whereRaw` because if I just add the `where` manually in `$all_categories`, the query works

```
    $all_categories = HmsBbrCategory::where('category_name', 'LIKE', "%Gen%") 
                                      ->orderBy('category_id', 'ASC')
                                      ->get();
```

[image: 2]

how do I get my if condition `whereRaw` to work?

**Updates:** I am trying to get the whereRaw to work first but I am encountering some issues:

```
    $all_categories = HmsBbrCategory::whereRaw('category_name LIKE '%Gen%'') 
                                      ->orderBy('category_id', 'ASC')
                                      ->get();
```

This code gives the error:

[image: 3]

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below

```
  $all_categories = HmsBbrCategory::where('category_name', 'LIKE','%Gen%') 
                                    ->orderBy('category_id', 'ASC')
                                    ->get();
```

or

```
  $all_categories = HmsBbrCategory::whereRaw('category_name LIKE "%Gen%"') 
                                    ->orderBy('category_id', 'ASC')
                                    ->get();
```

or

```
  $all_categories = HmsBbrCategory::whereRaw('category_name LIKE ?',["%Gen%"]) 
                                        ->orderBy('category_id', 'ASC')
                                        ->get();
```

if you see `whereRaw` method first it accept sql and second param it accept bindings

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but the whereRaw you are showing gives the error: `"message": "SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column \"%Gen%\" does not exist\nLINE 1: ... from \"hms_bbr_category\" where category_name LIKE \"%Gen%\" or...\n`

Comment: was about to comment again actually, adding the quotes still gives me the same error

Comment: and also, if i add single quotes, i get the error:     `"message": "Use of undefined constant Gen - assumed 'Gen' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)",`

Comment: @GetSomeHelp can post your latest query in comment which you tried now

Comment: @GetSomeHelp it should be whereRaw('category_name LIKE "%Gen%"')  as mentioned in my answer.you should use double quote not single quote

Comment: yes sir like i mentioned the double quotes is giving me the same error (undefined column)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $all_category = HmsBbrCategory::orderBy('category_id', 'ASC');
    if (empty($search_category)) {
        $all_category->where('category_id', '>=', 1);
    } else {
        $all_category->where(DB::raw('category_name ', 'LIKE', '%Gen%'));
    }
    $all_categories = $all_category->get();
```

I hope it would work for you.

Comment: tried this, table rows are not showing up

Comment: Are you checked you have data in table and which condition satisfied in this? check with  one by one log

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using `query()`

```
    $all_categories = HmsBbrCategory::query()
                                    ->when(empty($search_category), function ($query) {
                                        $query->where('category_id', '>=', '1');
                                    })
                                    ->when(!empty($search_category), function ($query) {
                                        $query->where('category_name', 'LIKE', "%Gen%");
                                    })
                                      ->orderBy('category_id', 'ASC')
                                      ->get();
```